# How do I statically link zstd library to my dynamic library?

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries, static-libraries, static-linking

I am trying to statically link zstd library(I have libzstd.a or libzstd.so) to my shared library libtest.so. The idea is that when deploying libtest.so in our application, we don't have to depend on libzstd.a or libzstd.so any more, so we have to statically link the zstd library.

I tried these:

```
cc  -fPIC -Wl,-soname=libtest.so -static-libgcc  -shared -o libtest.so myobjects.o -ldl -lc -L/path/to/libzstd -l:libzstd.a
cc  -fPIC -Wl,-soname=libtest.so -static-libgcc  -shared -o libtest.so myobjects.o -ldl -lc -Wl,-Bstatic -L/path/to/libzstd -l:libzstd.a
cc  -fPIC -Wl,-soname=libtest.so -static-libgcc  -shared -o libtest.so myobjects.o -ldl -lc /path/to/libzstd/libzstd.a
```

But they're all giving me this error:

```
/bin/ld: /path/to/libzstd/libzstd.a(zstd_common.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; 
recompile with -fPIC
/path/to/libzstd/libzstd.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libtest.so] Error 1
```

What are the problem here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All object files that are linked into a shared library must be compiled
as Position Independent Code (compiler option `-fPIC`).

The linker error:

```
/bin/ld: /path/to/libzstd/libzstd.a(zstd_common.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.1' can not be used when making a shared object; 
recompile with -fPIC
```

is telling you that the linkage of the shared library `libtest.so` needs the object file `zstd_common.o` from the
archive `libzstd.a`, but that object file was not compiled with `-fPIC`.

So you must rebuild `libzstd.a` from source, this time compiling the object
files that it contains with `-fPIC`.

Comment: Yes I found it out last night too. Recompiled libzstd.a with -fPIC on all source files, and now it links fine. Thank you!